# QGraphicsTextItem doesn't change position

Tags: c++, qt

I try to add `QGraphicsTextItem` with text in a defined position but the text is always in the left top corner of QGraphicsWidget. Here is the simple code:

```
QGraphicsTextItem* textItem= new QGraphicsTextItem(QString::number(i));
            textItem->setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 12));
            textItem->setTextWidth(50);
            textItem->setDefaultTextColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
            textItem->setPos(QPoint(300,300)));
```

Then I read that `QGraphicsTextItem` has its own `boundingBox` and maybe the bounding box has `leftTop` corner at `(0,0)`. That's why I tried changed the bounding box coordinates:

```
textItem->boundingRect().setWidth(50);
            textItem->boundingRect().setHeight(50);
            textItem->boundingRect().setTopLeft(QPoint(100,100));
```

But when I print the `boundingBox` size and topLeft coordinates after these changes, there are always the same:

```
textItem->boundingRect();
                std::cout << textItem.topLeft().x() << std::endl;
                std::cout << textItem.topLeft().y() << std::endl;
                std::cout << textItem.height() << std::endl;
                std::cout << textItem.width() << std::endl;
```

The results:

```
0
0
32
50
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to move the text to the set position?

Comment: I cant understand, Do you want to change its position by mouse? or you want to set it in a certain positon

Comment: In certain point. But it is always in (0,0) even when I add setPos(Qpoint(300,300)).

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsView` is rendering your `QGraphicsScene`. A scene can have a geometry, independent from the geometry of the `QGraphicsView`

from the [QGraphicsScene::sceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)  documentation:

> This property holds the scene rectangle; the bounding rectangle of the
> scene
>
> The scene rectangle defines the extent of the scene. It is primarily
> used by QGraphicsView to determine the view's default scrollable area,
> and by QGraphicsScene to manage item indexing.
>
> If unset, or if set to a null QRectF, sceneRect() will return the
> largest bounding rect of all items on the scene since the scene was
> created (i.e., a rectangle that grows when items are added to or moved
> in the scene, but never shrinks).

So, if you don't want scrolling, you simply need to set the `sceneRect`, to (0,0) for x,y and width and height as same as your `QGraphicsView` that is rendering your scene.

In your code, I think that you don't set a `sceneRect` for your scene and the size of your scene will be the same as the only child item it has.

Comment: I tried to change item sceneBoundingRect by using item->sceneBoundingRect().setRect(newX, newY, width, height) but it seems like it doesn't work (the parameters of scene bounding box are still the same). I am not sure why but the sceneBoundingBox has left top corner where I set position for the textItem (in 300,300) and the size of textItem but textItem->boundingBox() has left corner at (0,0) and I can't change it (by setRect)

Comment: you should call setSceneRect. The way you are doing now, is just get a copy of the QRect and set its bounds which has nothing to do with your scene.

Answer (score 0):

From [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) doc:

> QGraphicsView can be used to visualize a whole scene, or only parts of
> it. The visualized area is by default detected automatically when the
> view is displayed for the first time (by calling
> QGraphicsScene::itemsBoundingRect()). To set the visualized area
> rectangle yourself, you can call setSceneRect().

```
 auto scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,width(),height());
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QGraphicsTextItem* textItem= new QGraphicsTextItem(QString::number(1234));
                textItem->setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 12));
                textItem->setTextWidth(50);
                textItem->setDefaultTextColor(QColor(0, 0, 0));
                textItem->setPos(QPoint(100,300));

      scene->addItem(textItem);
```

[image]

I add one QGraphicsView Item in mainwindow UI ,then create one scene in the constructor of mainwindow , then It is importent that you **setSceneRect** like this `scene->setSceneRect(0,0,width(),height());`